# Queried date value moves by 2 days

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to learn Spring Data and am using JpaRepository to try and query date objects from the database. However, every time I query for a date, the result is always two days ahead of my expected value. The time component seems to be correct; it's just the date that is wrong. Thing is, it only looks like it happens if I compile the code on my machine. Doing it in another person's yields the correct results. Are there any things that I need to look at for this?  Any help would be very much appreciated.

DB Value: 2014-05-29 19:47:00.576

testRepo() below returns 2014-05-27 19:47:00.576 instead.

```
public void testRepo() {            
    System.out.println(repo.findByName("TESTDATE").getValue()); 
}
```

==========

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager em;

public DateObject findByName(String name) {

    StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
    sql.append("select * ");
    sql.append("from static_dates ");
    sql.append("where name = '" + name + "'");      

    Query q = em.createNativeQuery(sql.toString(), DateObject.class);

    List<DateObject> resultList = q.getResultList();

    System.out.println(resultList.get(0).getValue());

    return resultList.get(0);
}
```

=========

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "static_dates") 
public class DateObject {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private Date value;

    public Date getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Date value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Additionally, saving date values yields a correct result. For example, if I invoke repo.save( ... ) and pass the current system date, the same value reflects in the database. Only the SELECT calls seem to be incorrect.

Comment: It seems that are nothing wrong with your code, said that, I would ask if you are connecting to the same database of your code is?

Comment: Yes. Updating the value in the database also changes the result of the test method (again, with the result two days ahead of the expected date). The only difference that I know of that I'm doing is adding MSSQL's sendTimeAsDatetime=false connection property, but I highly doubt that this is the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by updating my MS SQL driver from v3.0 to v4.0.

Comment: v3 probably used 1899-12-30 as the base date (an artifact from Excel and some other programs), and v4 uses 1900-01-01 (which is more in line with SQL Server's base date).